# importing FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in Component file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a reactive form that I want to put in a generated component of `boom-covers`. I'm using the property `[formGroup]`:

```
<form name="boomCovers" method="post" id="bomCovers" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" [formGroup]="boomCoversForm">
...
</form>
```

I'm getting the old chestnut of:

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'
```

I know I need to:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

But because it's a component and not a page, I have no `boom-covers.module.ts` file to do the imports in there, only:

```
boom-covers.component.html
boom-covers.component.scss
boom-covers.component.spec.ts
boom-covers.component.ts
```

So how do I work my way around this?

I've tried to put it in `app-module.ts` but it seems to make no difference. I've had this problem a few times before and I've never been able to work out how to sort this out.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [ 
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Does anyone have a viable solution or am I just speaking complete nonsense?

Basically, how do I do a successful import of the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` if my component doesn't have a `.module.ts` file accompanying it? (which it doesn't by default)

Any help or guidance would be appreciated as I've lost count of the working hours I've poured into this with nothing to show for it.

Comment: if your application is complicated, yes, you can use several modules files. But it's not obligatory for small project. You can use just app.module.ts, Be sure that declarations: [AppComponent, BoomCovers], have BoomCovers

Comment: You can create a boom-covers.module.ts file with the components as well. However, your declarations do not have BoomCoversComponent. That is why the module cannot find the component

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here.

1. Use the new standalone components and import the modules directly into them.
2. The easiest way is to add your boom-covers component into 'declarations' array in app.module.ts.

For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, BoomCoversComponent],
  imports: [ 
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: thanks everyone. I have a shared.module.ts that controls the import of all the components and then imports that into the app.module.ts . I didn't realise I could just put  the imports into that shared file. I've got it working. You've all helped me immensely!

Comment: @jimbeeer a shared module is a good idea, but don't forget to take a look to standalone components, its a new feature from angular 15 :)

Comment: I shall be sure to check that out, thanks for the heads up.